# SOAP UI date variables for most recent Jan, Feb.., Dec over the last 12 months

Tags: groovy, scripting, soapui

I need to setup my mock responses such that they always provide data for the last 12 months. I know I can do that using variables such as today: ${=def now = new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd") within the project and call this using

```
${#Project#today}
```

as described here [Scripting Today's Date](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/SoapUI_scripting_today_s_date?lang=en)

However, I need much more control on the dates and I need to be able to have parts of the response always be for example the most recent month of February, March, etc. So given that today is April 14th, the most recent march would be March 1st, 2019, but the most recent July would be July 1st, 2018. How would I go about calculating variables that reflect the most recent month's date for each one of the 12 months of the year?

Has anyone tried anything similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took quite a bit of trial and error, but ultimately a figured it out. I had to create several additional variables first to keep track of current and last year and then get an if statement to work for that variable. Snapshot below:

[image]